# How do I make a tableview show in front of a drawn line? Currently, my drawRect method covers my table with white space

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

The purpose of this code is the add items in an order to a tableview, and then draw a line at the bottom of the table that looks like the bottom of a receipt. Separately, these two things work, but when combined, the table is not visible.

Here is my drawRect method

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGFloat components[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(colorspace, components);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);
int bottom = rect.size.height;
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, bottom);
for (int i=0; i<rect.size.width; i = i + 20) {
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, i + 10, bottom - 10);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, i + 20, bottom);
}
CGContextStrokePath(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
CGColorRelease(color);
}
```

Here is my viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

id item1 = @{@"item":@"Burger", @"cost":@"$3.50"};
id item2 = @{@"item":@"Fry", @"cost":@"$1.50"};

items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[items addObject: item1];
[items addObject: item2];

[orderItemsTable reloadData];

[self adjustHeightOfTableview];

DrawReceipt *receipt = [[DrawReceipt alloc] initWithFrame:orderItemsTable.frame];
receipt.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:receipt];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you could increase your row count by 1.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return receiptRows + 1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if (indexPath.row == receiptRows) {
    return 1;
  }
  return rowHeight;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if (indexPath.row == receiptRows) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"bottom-line"];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    return cell;
  }
  return yourOriginalCells;
}
```

**Edit**: If you want your content to scroll, but the last line stay put, how about:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  myTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
  UIView *bottomLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 100, 1)];
  [bottomLine setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
  [self.view addSubview:bottomLine];
}
```

If you want your background below the `UITableView` but your bottom line above it, they need to be in two different views.

Comment: I considered this, but i'm wanting the user to be able to scroll through the tableView without the bottom line actually moving, hence why I don't want to put the line in the last cell.